# View is moved up when using vertical autoresize

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xib

In my custom drawn window I have a NSTextView under which I'd like to have NSScrollView separated by empty space. That's how I've set it up in xib.

In interface builder it looks fine, with nice space between the two of them
[image]

But when I run the program, the scroll view gets moves upwards, actually covering the text view:
[image]

But when I disable vertical autoresize of the scroll view, everything is working as it should.

text view and scroll view are under NSView so they are siblings to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it was shortcoming of the system as the scroll view was being completely hidden and so then it was probably moved.

I've worked it out by subclassing NSScrollView and overriding
   - (void)resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:(NSSize)oldSize_;
So now I can position the scroll view exactly as I wish.